How to hide a button in Laravel Blade?
I am working on a Laravel project, and I need to hide a specific button in the admin panel. The button is located in a Blade file that looks like this:
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-primary action" data-href="{{ route('credit-card-accept', $bill->id) }}">
        <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
    </button>
</td>

I want to hide this button entirely, but only for certain cases (e.g., when a specific condition is met). How can I do this? I’ve tried wrapping it in an @if statement, but I’m not sure how to properly implement this in Blade.
@if(false)
    <button>...</button>
@endif

But this hardcodes the button to always hide.
What I need: A dynamic solution to hide the button based on conditions in the controller or model.

dynamic means, when you don't do any actions, if some condition is changed by another user(admin), do you want to hide or show the button?

Welcome to SO. "only for certain cases" - so set a variable based on that case in your controller, and test the variable in your view.  BTW you're likely to get a better response if you take at least some basic care with formatting of your question.

Don't confuse "hidden" and "not rendered". If you use @if(false)<button>...</button>@endif, the <button> element won't even show up as HTML on your document. So if you wanted to "unhide it", you can't without a complete re-render of your page. Something like <button class="{{ $hidden ? 'hidden' : '' }}">...</button> (or similar) would be how you render, but hide the button, which can then be unhidden by simply removing that hidden class. Also be aware of the security implications; a hidden button can be unhidden by anyone with some HTML manipulation, an un-rendered button cannot.

@if(false)
    <button>...</button>
@endif

In this part false should be variable, not false itself.
As you set it false, it shows hidden.
Here is my reference.
Firstly in your controller, you should set the value.
public function Bill()  
{  
    $bill = Bill::find($id);  
    $condition = $bill->some_property === 'your value'; // Set your condition here  

    return view('bill_view', compact('bill', 'condition'));  
}  

And in your view:
<td>  
    @if(!$condition) <!-- Assuming you want to hide the button when condition is true -->  
        <button class="btn btn-primary action" data-href="{{ route('credit-card-accept', $bill->id) }}">  
            <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>  
        </button>  
    @endif  
</td> 

Hope it works for you.
